# Дана переменная, в которой находится словарь. Задача удалить ключ словаря, если в значении этого ключа ничего нет

Tags: python, функции, циклы

Дана следующая переменная:

```
directories = {
'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
'2': ['10006'],
'3': [],
'4': ['154'],
'5': []
}
```

нужно написать функцию, при вызове которой программа спросит номер ключа и в случае если в ключе нет значений удалит это ключ. Если есть значения, то ничего не сделает.
На данный момент реализовал часть функции, но она удаляя ключ в итоге выдает ошибку, а именно введенный ключ в одинарных кавычках:

```
def d():
    doc_number = input("Введите номер документа, который хотите удалить: ")
    dict_ = directories.copy()
    for k, v in list(dict_.items()):
        if v == []:
            del directories[doc_number]
            return ('Полка удалена')

d()
```

Подскажите что делаю не так. Спасибо

Comment: Только не понятно, зачем копировать словарь, и для чего нужно его перебирать) Получили ключ - проверяйте ровно это значение, через `directories.get(key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': [],
    '4': ['154'],
    '5': []
}


def d(dc):
    key = input("Введите номер документа, который хотите удалить: ")
    try:
        if len(dc[key]) == 0:
            del dc[key]
            return 'Полка удалена'
    except:
        return 'Key does not exists'
    return 'Ничего не произошло'


print(d(directories))
```

Либо:

```
def d(dc):
    key = input("Введите номер документа, который хотите удалить: ")
    if not dc.get(key, 1):
        del dc[key]
        return 'Полка удалена'
    return 'Ничего не произошло'
```

Comment: вместо `len(dc[key]) == 0` лучше `not dc[key]`

Comment: @Danis, да. Никак не привыкну, что `bool([]) == False`

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите как работает эта строка: if not dc.get(key, 1):

Comment: `dc.get(key, 1)` - `key` - ключ. Берем из `dc` значение по ключу `key`. Если такого ключа нет в словаре, то вернет значение 1.